# Linearly independent subset of a spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given $V_1 + V_2 \in \operatorname{Sp} \{V_1,..,V_n\}$ and $V_1 \notin \operatorname{Sp}\{V_2,...,V_n\}$, prove that $\{V_2,...,V_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Well, I know that $ V_1 + V_2 \in a_1V_1,..,a_nV_n$ and $V_1 \notin a_2V_2,...,a_nV_n$

I need to show that $a_1V1+...+a_nVn \ne 0$ if $A_i \ne 0$.

I don't have any clue how to keep going from here to prove that. Any ideas?

Comment: $v_1+v_2\in\operatorname{Sp}\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ by definition, so the first hypothesis just tells you that $n\ge2$. As a counterexample, consider $v_1\ne0$, and $v_2=v_3=\dots=v_n=0$.

Comment: Actually you can not say that $v_1 \ne 0$ I believe, and even if you can, it's just right only when $v_1 \ne 0$. Do you have a more general solution? Although @DonAntonio gave a pretty nice solution to it.

Comment: There's no “more general solution”: my example just shows that the claim is false. You can't derive any conclusion about linear independence of $\{v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ just by knowing there's a vector not belonging to its span.

Comment: When $v_2 = v_3 = v_n = 0$ it means {0} and {0} is linear independent. Right?

Comment: No, $\{0\}$ is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given the claim's false:

Over the real field $\;\Bbb R\;$ :

$$\binom10+\binom01\in\text{Span}\left\{\;\binom10\;,\;\;\binom01\;,\;\;\binom02\;\right\}\;\;and\;\;\binom10\notin\text{Span}\left\{\;\binom01\;,\;\;\binom02\;\right\}$$

yet

$$\left\{\;\binom01\;,\;\;\binom02\;\right\}\;\;\;\text{is linearly dependent}$$